# UISearchBar Animation

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

It's common to see a UISearchBar in an application, that upon a click, will enlarge and animate into view with a keyboard. I'm curious, is this something the iPhone SDK provides for free, or is the Animation code more than likely written by the developer? I use a UISearchBar in several controllers, however by default a keyboard just pops into view, the search bar does not animate in any fashion. This is also very prominent in apps that have a search icon. How is it typically done?

Comment: Which are some of the applications that employ the animation you're referring to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a discussion ["UISearchBar like Contacts"](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1652157&tstart=0) on this at the apple site.

Answer (score 5):

This can be easily implemented using the UISearchDisplayController using the iPhone SDK 3.0 and above.

See the TableSearch example project, included in the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Did you put it in through Interface Builder or programatically? Because by default the keyboard animation should play.